# Evaluate $\int_{\Bbb S^n}\int_{\Bbb S^n}|s-t|^{-\lambda}\,{\rm d}s\,{\rm d}t$

Tags: integration, inequality, multiple-integral, spheres

I'm reading the proof for HLS inequality in *Analysis* written by Michael Loss and Elliott H.Lieb. The HLS inequality is
$$\left|\int_{\Bbb R^n}\int_{\Bbb R^n}f(x)|x-y|^{-\lambda}g(y)\,{\rm d}x\,{\rm d}y\right|\le C(n,\lambda,p)\|f\|_p\|g\|_r,\qquad 1/p+1/r+\lambda/n=2.$$
He found the best function when $p=r=2n/(2n-\lambda)$, that is
$$
h(x)=|\Bbb S^n|^{-1/p}\left(\cfrac2{1+|x|^2}\right)^{n/p}.
$$
Then he said that if $f(x)=g(y)=h(x)$, you can get the integral on the left side is
$$
\pi^{\lambda/2}\cfrac{\Gamma(n/2-\lambda/2)}{\Gamma(n-\lambda/2)}\left(\cfrac{\Gamma(n/2)}{\Gamma(n)}\right)^{-1+\lambda/n}.
$$
It is hard for me to calculate this integral, I think it should use the fact that
$$
\mathcal Sh(x)=|\Bbb S^n|^{-1/p},~~~~~\text{where $\mathcal S$ is the  stereographic project.}
$$
Thus we only need to calculate
$$
\int_{\Bbb S^n}\int_{\Bbb S^n}|s-t|^{-\lambda}\,{\rm d}s\,{\rm d}t.
$$
But I cannot solve this one, could you give me some advice? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can fix one point, then integrate relative to that axis. For example for a unit circle you get a factor of $2 \pi$ for the first point, and then integrate $((1-x)^2+y^2)^{-\lambda /2}*2/y dx$ where $y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$. Trig substitution probably simplifies things.

Comment: Thank you, Eric. But I had tries this way, my trouble is that after I write this out, I can still not solve the integral for $s$. I don't how you get the $*2/y$, this is important for the integral, could you tell me the formula? Thanks for advance.

Comment: That’s the cross section - the surface is at an angle, so you it’s something like $Surface(y)*dx/y$ where in the circle case the surface is 2 for top and bottom two points, in a sphere it’s the entire cross section circle, so it’s $2\pi y$. Note that for the sphere case, you get the surface of cross sections is proportional to $dx$. I’m not sure the nicest ways of simplifying from there - for $\lambda=1$ In 3d, it’ll simplify (it’s same as electrostatic shell potential energy), otherwise idk.

Comment: Oh, thank you. I'm not realize it entirely, but I know that there is such a formula for complex sphere. I need more time to realize it. It seems that I can't simply calculate the surface measure when $s_1$ is fixed. It contains the calculation of curvature.

Answer (score 2):

*I'm using the notation $\mathbb{S}^n:=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:|x|=1\}$ in this answer.*

$J(s)=\int_{\mathbb{S}^n}|s-t|^{-\lambda}{\rm d}t$ doesn't (actually) depend on $s\in\mathbb{S}^n$, so that $$\int_{\mathbb{S}^n}\int_{\mathbb{S}^n}\frac{{\rm d}s\,{\rm d}t}{|s-t|^\lambda}=S_n J(s_0),$$ where $S_n=\dfrac{2\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma(n/2)}$ is the measure of $\mathbb{S}^n$, and $s_0=(1,0,\dots,0)$ say.

Next, each $t\in\mathbb{S}^n$ can be written as $(x,t')$ with $x\in[-1,1]$ and $t'\in\sqrt{1-x^2}\,\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$; the corresponding decomposition of the integral over $\mathbb{S}^n$ of a function $f$ is \begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb{S}^n}f(t)\,{\rm d}t
&=\int_{-1}^1\int_{\sqrt{1-x^2}\,\mathbb{S}^{n-1}}f(x,t')\,{\rm d}t'\frac{{\rm d}x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}
\\&=\int_{-1}^1(1-x^2)^{(n-3)/2}\int_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}}f(x,t\sqrt{1-x^2})\,{\rm d}t\,{\rm d}x.
\end{align}

In our case, for $t=(x,t')$, the quantity $|s_0-t|^2=2(1-x)$ depends on $x$ only, thus $$\int_{\mathbb{S}^n}\int_{\mathbb{S}^n}\frac{{\rm d}s\,{\rm d}t}{|s-t|^\lambda}=S_n S_{n-1}\int_{-1}^1\frac{(1-x^2)^{(n-3)/2}}{\big(2(1-x)\big)^{\lambda/2}}\,{\rm d}x,$$ and the last integral is of [beta type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) (after $x=1-2y$). The result is

$$\int_{\mathbb{S}^n}\int_{\mathbb{S}^n}\frac{{\rm d}s\,{\rm d}t}{|s-t|^\lambda}=\frac{2^{n-\lambda}\pi^{n-1/2}\Gamma\big((n-1-\lambda)/2\big)}{\Gamma(n/2)\Gamma(n-1-\lambda/2)}.$$

Comment: Thank you. I think the most important step is the formula which tells us how to change the integral on $S^n$ into $(-1,1)$. I found the formula in Grafakos's book *Classical Fourier analysis* (GTM 249). I want to share it with you. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @IMOS: A mistake made a year ago ;) Fixed now.